# Android Studio Manifest merger failed minSdkVersion Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to add a dependency in my app which has the minimum sdk version newer than my apps so I am getting the following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.nononsenseapps.filepicker" to force usage

but I don't know where to add that suggestion so I can build it.
This is how my build.gradle(Module: app) looks right now

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.codedspycamera.android"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'


}
```

Comment: make `minsdkversion 14`

Comment: can't make it because I am handling different android versions in my code to make it compatible with older android versions.

Comment: com.nononsenseapps:filepicker's minSdkVersion is 14. So Either change your minSdkVersion to 14 or remove com.nononsenseapps:filepicker and try some other similar library which supports minSdkVersion 9.

Comment: how did you add the library as a module or a jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make the answer more clear for everyone this is what you have to do

tools:overrideLibrary marker

A special marker that can only be used with uses-sdk declaration to override importing a library which minimum SDK version is more recent than that application's minimum SDK version.
Without such a marker, the manifest merger will fail. The marker will allow users to select which libraries can be imported ignoring the minimum SDK version.

Example, In the main android manifest :

```
 <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="2"
          tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
```

will allow the library with the following manifest to be imported without error :

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lib1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
</manifest>
```

Note that the if multiple libraries are added than they must be separated with a comma ","

Answer (score 2):

`com.nononsenseapps.filepicker` works only on >=14 version android device. I think it will crash if you force it to work on <14 devices. But anyway if you want to do this, you should force using minSdkVersion params from your main app to override library value. Add suggested line to main app manifest. [Read this for more information.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker)

Answer (score 0):

For ionic developers

config.xml -  add -

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

bundle.gradle - add

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```