# Android Studio Error: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:mindkVersion 11 cannt be smaller than version 14

Tags: android

I had a question (Who doesn't here) anyway I have tried many things and many similar topics here on stack overflow and I thought well I cant get it still so why not ask, I hope you all know something but here are some pictures, keep in mind that I have never had this problem before neither encountered it

[Android Studio Manifest merger failed minSdkVersion Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525725/android-studio-manifest-merger-failed-minsdkversion-error) is related but not exact and our code is different it seems so that sadly has not helped me

[Here is the error, happens when I try to sync/build the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO6Gd.png)

Comment: if the image is not showing here is the imgur:
http://i.imgur.com/KeXn8wc.png

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the minimum sdk of google play services since the minimum for it is 14 so I recommend you to make your minimum sdk of your app to be 14.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Check your build.gradle and set the minimum sdk their